# How can I ensure that my app is only available to phones on Android Market?

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I have an application that has not yet been optimised for xlarge tablet screens, so I have the following code the manifest:

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```

However, when I upload the .apk file to Android Market, it tells me:

API level: 4-12+
**Supported screens: small-xlarge**
OpenGL textures: all

I know that it is currently possible to filter an application to only run on phones with:

```
<uses-sdk android:maxSdkVersion="10" />
```

...but I want the application to be available for phones running Ice Cream Sandwich when they appear.

Comment: what is your `uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion` set to?

Comment: @jdamcd: Is the app published? If so, you might want to post a link to it, so we can see if it actually shows up for tablets in the Market. That's a more certain test.

Comment: From uses-sdk guide regarding `maxSdkVersion`: Warning: Declaring this attribute is not recommended.  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: @CrackerJack9: The minSdkVersion is 4 and I have no maxSdkVersion.

Comment: @CommonsWare: The app is https://market.android.com/details?id=org.musicbrainz.mobile and I've been able to download it to my 10" tablet, which runs Android 3.1, through Android Market.

Comment: @jdamcd you question includes `android:maxSdkVersion="10"`. Also, you can confirm by going to Edit Application, down by Supported Devices, there is a Show Devices link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you try using:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html

```
<compatible-screens>
```

> Android Market filters the application if the device screen size and
>   density does not match any of the screen configurations ....

Comment: I'm hoping for a better solution than listing the 12 different screen configurations I want to support. :(

Comment: @jdamcd: Sorry, but that's the right answer. I misread your question and thought you were using `<compatible-screens>`.

Comment: I guess this is the way to go then. It's a little confusing that <supports-screens> is not used to filter the "Supported screens" in Market.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found the solution.

If I remove this line from the xml it works out:

```
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
    <supports-screens 
        android:xlargeScreens="false"  />
</gap:config-file>
```