# How to restrict that app will not run on tablet only not on phone

Tags: android

I am making an application which must run only on tablet not phones. I use this code but its installed even in mobile also.

Please help me how to make application for tablet only.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="false"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: There is a kind of answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361292/manifest-limits-to-only-tablets-but-app-is-still-available-to-samsung-galaxy-s2).
I think you should put anyDensity to false

Answer (score 1):

if you want your application to be available only to tablet devices, you can declare the element in your manifest like this:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                      android:normalScreens="false"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"
                      android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

for more refer this [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html)

Comment: I used the same support screen but still installing in 2.2 htc

Answer (score 1):

this may help you:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html
http://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html

```
<manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="false"
                      android:xlargeScreens="false"
    />
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

.

> Android Market filters the application if the device screen size and
>   density does not match any of the screen configurations ....

See also [How can I ensure that my app is only available to phones on Android Market?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223209/how-can-i-ensure-that-my-app-is-only-available-to-phones-on-android-market)

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code  to detect if device is a Tablet:

```
public boolean isTablet() {
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "CHECK_TABLET isTablet entry["+isTablet+"]");
        if (isTablet == null) {
            int deviceSizeMask = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
                    & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
            float screenDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;




            if (deviceSizeMask == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE
                    || (deviceSizeMask == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE && screenDensity < 2.0f)) {
                isTablet = true;
            } else {
                isTablet = false;
            }

            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "CHECK_TABLET deviceSizeMask["+deviceSizeMask+"] screenDensity["+screenDensity+"] isTablet["+isTablet+"]");
        }
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "CHECK_TABLET isTablet exit["+isTablet+"]");
        return isTablet;
    }
```